# NodeJS - Protect image url to only authorized user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, image

So I'm currently building an app. User would have the possibility to upload image. The image they upload should only be visible by them. So I'm wondering how I can achieve this considering the image is available through a URL.

Actually what I was thinking was, in order to get the picture, the user should do a REST API request and the api would return the image data if the user has the correct permission.

The frontend of my app is in React and the backend (Rest api) in nodeJS.

Edit: Actually the image are store on AWS S3 (this can change if needed)

Thanks !

Comment: Since you're saving also an url of the image somewhere in the db, you could add a field to this document with the user id so you could query the url  you want to show based on the user.id only or also can add a field to the user model with an array of its images urls i.e. images:[url], than just query user.images.

Comment: @vitomadio Yes ut everybody could guess the url and find the image :/ I just want the user to have access to his image

Comment: it depends, cus you can rewrite the image name with some encryption that will make very difficult to guess the url :)

Comment: @vitomadio Yes of course ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option to allow only authorized users to fetch an image is S3 Presigned URL You can refer to [the article](https://medium.com/@aakashbanerjee/upload-files-to-amazon-s3-from-the-browser-using-pre-signed-urls-4602a9a90eb5), it thoroughly describes how to implement S3 Presigned URL. [Another code example with Node JS](https://gist.github.com/pnedelko/15a0a65ed06db97e2a15). If you code in another language just google it "AWS S3 Presigned URL" and you will find it.